# How to navigate from a normal page to a MasterDetailPage using Prism.Forms framework?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism

So i have a splash screen and a LoginScreen, after the user logs in, then he's presented with a MasterDetailPage, and there's a option to logout, what i want to achieve is to clear the masterdetail navigation and go to the login page using Prism.Forms
But when i do "NavigationPage/LoginPage", it still has the MasterDetailPage Navigation active, is there a way to disable this behavior using Prism

[image: After Logging In]

[image: After leaving [![After Logging Again]MasteDetailNavigation][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXXz4.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXXz4.png)

Any help would be helpfull

Comment: I posted the answer for your question, but I strongly recommend you to edit and to format your question even more it is easier for community members to answer well fromatted questions.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your question you want to reset navigation stack and master-detail page and navigate to "clear" page for your login page. If you want to achieve that, you don't want to use `NavigationPage/LoginPage` you will need to use `Absolute navigation`, because using Absolute navigation in Prism you will be able to reset the entire navigation stack and it is equivalent to:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new SomePage()
```

You can find more about it [here](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/navigation-basics.html).

But basically what you need to do is to use Prism Absolute navigation like this:

```
//absolute short-syntax
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("/YourPage"); //notice the prefix /

//absolute URI-syntax
_navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("http://www.brianlagunas.com/YourPage", UriKind.Absolute));
```

*Code example is from Prism Library docs site*

Also I recommend you to take a look at my blog post [How to make Master-Detail Page Navigation menu in Xamarin.Forms with Prism](https://almirvuk.blogspot.com/2018/03/how-to-make-master-detail-page.html)

Wishing you lots of luck with coding!

Comment: thanks a lot for your inputs, this does work, but my problem is when i try to log out and go to another page, i still get that MasterDetailNavigation Stack details and it gets reflected

Comment: and how are you navigating to another page, show us a code which you are using it will be easier for us to help you

Comment: I've tried  await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("/MainPage", UriKind.Absolute));  await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage"), by clicking on the logout option in my masterdetail menu option

Comment: That is weird, and what is your MainPage? just some simple page or page with master detail menu?

Comment: Just a SimplePage with some entries to login @Almir Vuk